# ms access form closes when running query from button

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with one combo boxes and ok button. When a value from combo box is selected and clicked "OK", it opens a query based on the selected value.

That is fine, but it closes the  form and then opens the query. I have to again click on the form tab to select another value and run query.

Is it possible, query runs in another window while form window is still open?

For combo box

I have a code in row source like

```sql
select distinct format(columndate, 'mm-dd-yyyy') from table1
```

For OK Button,
   I have a code as below :

```vb
Private Sub Submit_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("query")
    strSQL = "SELECT columndate," & _
      "sum(qty1)," & _
      "sum(qty2)," & _
      "sum(qty3)," & _
      "sum(qy4)" & _
      "FROM table1 " & _
      "WHERE table1.column_date = '" & Me.datefield.value & "' " & _
      "group by table1.[columndate];"

    qdf.sql = strSQL
    DoCmd.Restore
    DoCmd.OpenQuery ("query")
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "Me.Form3"

    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    Debug.Print strSQL
End Sub
```

I have one more question on this. The date field in fact in the format "dd-mm-yyyy" in the table, but in query it shows blank result as long as I change the format to "mm-dd-yyyy" in row sources as in the first query here

Answer (score 0):

Your OK-button click handler would have to look like this

```
Private Sub btnOk_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenQuery(Me!cboQuery, acViewNormal, acReadOnly)
End Sub
```

Also make sure that the `Cancel` property of your button is set to `No`.

Comment: I tried acViewNormal as I updated in original question but still form closes when I click the button (closes means form window disappears and query window appears)...But I want to keep open form window...let query window to open in a small window in right or something like that

Comment: This code doesn't close the main form. At most it hides it, of the query window is bigger or if the forms are maximized. Call `DoCmd.Restore` before opening the query, if this is the case. This will un-maximize the windows.

Comment: As I see your code now: It is the line `DoCmd.Close acForm, "Me.Form3"` that closes the form (if "Form3" is the name of the form in question). Drop that line.

Comment: No, DoCmd.Close is not making any different, I tried removing this already. And I tried "Docmd.Restore" also as I updated in original, still the same. I'm not sure if I'm making mistake, or in access form, it will be like that..

Comment: Access will not close forms by itself. But if you want to close a form named "Form3", remove the "Me." from the string! `DoCmd.Close acForm, "Form3"`. There is no form called "Me.Form3" since the dot cannot be part of a form's name.

Comment: My suggestion is to set a breakpoint on the first line of your form and then step through the code. You will see where the form is closed.